# Integrating over integral limits

Tags: integration, analysis

What does $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big( \int_{x-1/2}^{x+1/2}f(t)dt \Big) dx$$

mean? Is it the same as $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$$ or do the boundaries "overlap"? Are there any good theorems to use here to access the limits of the integral? Is it possible to somehow change the order of integration?

I am trying to figure out this interval for a function $f$ with $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx=1$$

and I suspect that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big( \int_{x-1/2}^{x+1/2}f(t)dt \Big) dx=1$$

Comment: What happens when you switch the order of integration?

Comment: Not sure if I am allowed to do that! If I somehow could though, I would integrate over an integral of length 1 over an integral which I know equals 1, so I would get 1.

Comment: Draw a picture of the region of integration.  Note that if we switch the order of integration we have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \int_{t-1/2}^{t+1/2} (1)\,dx\,dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the function 
$g(x):=\int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^ {x+\frac{1}{2}}f(t)dt$ that assigns to every $x$ the value of the integral $\int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^ {x+\frac{1}{2}}f(t)dt$.

So the question is to calculate 
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx$.
You can observe that if you choose $y=t-x$ then

$g(x):=\int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^ {x+\frac{1}{2}}f(t)dt= \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^ {\frac{1}{2}}f(y+x)dy $

And so

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^ {\frac{1}{2}}f(y+x)dydx $

so (in the hypothesis in which you can change the order of integration) you have that

$  \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^ {\frac{1}{2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y+x)dxdy= \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^ {\frac{1}{2}} (\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)dz)dy$

$= \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^ {\frac{1}{2}}1dy=\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}=1$